# Grunt-newer with Grunt-uglify and Bower

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-contrib-uglify

I've got a project using Grunt and Bower. Grunt-uglify will concatenate/minify files from the Bower directory to the `deploy/scripts.js` folder. I'm using Grunt-newer so it will only update `deploy/scripts.js` if new files are added or changed. Everything works great...except...

When I add a new library with Bower, file date reflects when the file was uploaded to the Bower library (or whoever is hosting it), not the date it was create on my computer. Thus, Grunt-newer sees the new Bower libraries are being older than `deploy/scripts.js` and does not update the file.

One--cumbersome--solution is to open the new library .js file, and resave it. It modifies the file dates and thus, grunt-newer will create the `deploy/script.js` file. However, the usefulness of Bower seems moot with such an awkward solution.

Comment: Is using grunt-newer the answer here?  Perhaps grunt watch.

Comment: Please re-read the post above. Grunt-newer is correctly completing it's task; Bower is simply loading files with old created/modified dates. I don't see how Grunt-watch is relevant to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bower hooks](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md) in order to manipulate the files modification time. This is kind of a hack but can achieve what you are looking for.
You will need to register a *postinstall* hook and pass the list of updated components as an argument.  When the script is called, the % will be replaced with a space-separated list of components being installed or uninstalled.
The hooks should be registered in the `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "hook.sh %"
    }
}
```

Then you will need a script which iterates over the components and changes the modification time of the files.
For example a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in "$@"
do
    find "./bower_components/$var" -exec touch {} \;
done
```

Here is another example of a node.js script for the same purpose:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path')

var components = process.argv.slice(2)
components.forEach(function (comp) {
    var comp_path = path.join(process.cwd(),"bower_components",comp);
    var files = fs.readdirSync(comp_path);
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        fs.utimesSync(path.join(comp_path, file), new Date(), new Date());
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting solution; it is definitely a "hack" like you stated. I see two potential issues with this. 1) It depends on a shell script. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that wouldn't be a good solution for Windows users, semi-defeating the purpose of Bower/NodeJS/Grunt. 2) Anytime one Bower script is updated, all scripts modified dates would be updated. This would force Grunt-newer to update all Bower components even if only one changed.

Comment: @Jason (1) You can use another scripting language such as Javascript (you should have nodejs installed) (2) Bower will only pass the components which were installed so this should not be a problem

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to have an example of nodejs manipulating files in this way?

Comment: @Jason I added an example to my answer earlier today

Comment: @drob Gave the node.js example a try. Please bear with me here as I am quite inexperienced in node.js. I added the .bowerrc file with the Javascript object above. I pointed it to `script.js`. However, even with the script empty, I get a fairly hefty error. http://pastebin.com/1JgfKNJQ

Comment: @Jason you should register the hook like this: "postinstall": "node script.js %"

Comment: Cool. Script runs without errors, however, the modified dates did not change.